# jquery .when(f1, f2).then() returns object array for f1 but responseText for f2. Why?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, json, jquery

I have a jQuery `.when()` that makes two ajax calls, then passes the data along to another function:

```
function getTableData() {
   $.when(ajaxCall1(), ajaxCall2()).then(doStuff);
}
```

Both ajax methods are essentially the same, except they use different methods on the controller:

```
    function ajaxCall1() {
        return $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'Controller/ControllerMethod1',
        });
    }

    function ajaxCall2() {
        return $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'Controller/ControllerMethod2',
        });
    }
```

I would expect the data passed to `doStuff()` to be the same for each ajax method, but this doesn't appear to be the case.

```
    function doStuff(jsonData) {
        doStuffWithData(jsonData[0]);
        doMoreStuffWithData(jsonData[2]);
    }
```

I expected `jsonData[0]` and `jsonData[2]` to both contain an object array.  FireBug shows me the following for `jsonData[0]`:

```
[Object { Description="Completed", Id=3, ItemTypelist=[2]}, Object { Description="Completed - QC", Id=3, ItemTypelist=[2]}, Object { Description="Completed - Approval Needed", Id=3, ItemTypelist=[2]}, 5 more...]
```

`jsonData[2]` looks like this:

```
Object { readyState=4, responseText="[{"Description":"Comple...Item Type 2","Id":1}]}]", status=200, more...}
```

Why are these different?  I need `jsonData[2]` to be like `jsonData[0]`.

Comment: Why `jsonData[2]` and not `jsonData[1]`?

Comment: `jsonData[1]` is simply `"success"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the first and the before last examples on [this jQuery webpage](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/).

Currently you have doStuff(jsonData). jsonData corresponds to the returned array `[data, textStatus, jqXHR]` from the first Ajax query only ! So jsonData[0] is the data from the first query, jsonData[2] is the XHR from the first query. You must change doStuff such as:

```
doStuff(jsonData1, jsonData2)
{
  // jsonData1[0] holds data from ajax request 1
  // jsonData2[0] holds data from ajax request 2
}
```

Comment: You're welcome, I already hit a brick wall for a few hours on that issue ;-)